# How to not make install step when building external project with cmake

Tags: cmake, dependencies, installation, project

I'm building dependency project with cmake ExternalProject_Add command:

```
include(ExternalProject)
...
set(COMMON_BASE_PROJECT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../CommonBase)

ExternalProject_Add(CommonBaseProject
  SOURCE_DIR ${COMMON_BASE_PROJECT_DIR}
  BINARY_DIR ${COMMON_BASE_PROJECT_DIR}/build
  INSTALL_COMMMAND ""
)   

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
include_directories(${COMMON_BASE_PROJECT_DIR}/include)

add_library(
    ${LIBRARY_NAME}
    SHARED
    ${SRC_FILES}
    ${INCLUDE_FILES}
)

target_link_libraries (Bios ${COMMON_BASE_PROJECT_DIR}/build/libCommonBase.dll)
add_dependencies(Bios CommonBaseProject)
```

but i get error:

```
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libCommonBase.dll
[100%] Built target CommonBase
[ 50%] Performing install step for 'CommonBaseProject'
make[3]: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

I don't need to make install step, so my question is: how to disable it?

Comment: Do you mean to delete " INSTALL_COMMMAND """ line? I've tried but result is the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can generate a target for the build step with `STEP_TARGETS build` and add dependency on this particular target. The step targets are named `<external-project-name>-<step-name>` so in this case the target representing the build step will be named `CommonBaseProject-build`.

You probably also want to exclude the CommonBaseProject from the "all" target with `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE`.

```
ExternalProject_Add(CommonBaseProject
  SOURCE_DIR ${COMMON_BASE_PROJECT_DIR}
  BINARY_DIR ${COMMON_BASE_PROJECT_DIR}/build
  STEP_TARGETS build
  EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE
)

add_dependencies(Bios CommonBaseProject-build)
```

Comment: Is there a way to later call the install step manually for the external project? For example as part of the main project's install step?

Comment: You can `add_dependencies(install CommonBaseProject-install)` but that will not install the external project globally. If not changed this will install to local build dir.

Answer (score 18):

You almost had it: Instead of `INSTALL_COMMAND ""` put something like

```
    INSTALL_COMMAND cmake -E echo "Skipping install step."
```

Comment: You could also use the `true` or `:` commands, which do nothing, i.e. `INSTALL_COMMAND true`. But it will still display `Performing install step`.

Comment: this works!    `INSTALL_COMMAND ""`  is not enough, cmake will still run a `install` step.

Answer (score 0):

Since at least CMake 3.10 the empty string is sufficient to suppress the install step:

> Passing an empty string as the `<cmd>` makes the install step do nothing.

The same goes for the other stages; see the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/ExternalProject.html) for more.

If you're still building with CMake <3.10 then you need to update CMake ;)

Answer (score -1):

Not relevant to your question, which it was already answered, but in my case I had the following `ExternalProject_Add` directive:

```
ExternalProject_Add(external_project
    # [...]
    # Override build/install command
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND
        "${CMAKE_COMMAND}"
        --build .
        --target INSTALL    # Wrong casing for "install" target
       --config ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
)
```

In this case cmake quits with very similar error (`*** No rule to make target 'INSTALL'`), but in this case it's the external project that is looking for incorrect uppercase `INSTALL` target: correct case is `install` instead. Apparently, that worked in Windows with MSVC but fails in unix operating systems.