# C++ project with OpenCV as external using cmake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm new to cmake, and could't figure out how to achieve this after a few days.

I'm trying to build a C++ project that depends on OpenCV using cmake, but I want cmake to clone and install it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38026254/4969574). I found a [project's CMakeFile](https://github.com/kerberos-io/machinery/blob/master/cmake/External-OpenCV.cmake) that I'm using as reference to accomplish this.So I have this:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


int main() {
    std::cout << "OpenCV Version: " + cv::getVersionString() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(cv_playground)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(Git REQUIRED)

include(ExternalProject)

# OpenCV
set(OPENCV_INSTALL_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/opencv)
ExternalProject_Add(opencv
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/opencv/opencv
        GIT_TAG 68942affdbc4677aa845bc4307d4752182324a0e # 4.0.0-alpha
        SOURCE_DIR opencv
        BINARY_DIR opencv-build
        CMAKE_ARGS
          -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${OPENCV_INSTALL_LOCATION}
        )
include_directories(${OPENCV_INSTALL_LOCATION}/include/opencv4)
link_directories(${OPENCV_INSTALL_LOCATION}/lib)

add_executable(cv_playground main.cpp)
add_dependencies(cv_playground opencv)
target_link_libraries(cv_playground opencv_core opencv_dnn opencv_features2d opencv_flann opencv_highgui opencv_imgcodecs)
```

But when building the project I get a lot of undefined references (pthread, gz, dlopen/dlclose, itt_domain_create_ptr, etc)

I would like to know how to fix those undef refs, I already installed pthread, zlib, etc but I don't know how to make cmake to use them. I tried to add them in the `target_link_libraries` for example but still gives me the same errors:

CMakeLists.txt (note the CMAKE_DL_LIBS in target_link_libraries):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(cv_playground)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_package(Git REQUIRED)

include(ExternalProject)

# OpenCV
set(OPENCV_INSTALL_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/opencv)
ExternalProject_Add(opencv
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/opencv/opencv
        GIT_TAG 68942affdbc4677aa845bc4307d4752182324a0e # 4.0.0-alpha
        SOURCE_DIR opencv
        BINARY_DIR opencv-build
        CMAKE_ARGS
          -DWITH_OPENGL=OFF
          -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${OPENCV_INSTALL_LOCATION}
        )
include_directories(${OPENCV_INSTALL_LOCATION}/include/opencv4)
link_directories(${OPENCV_INSTALL_LOCATION}/lib)

add_executable(cv_playground main.cpp)
add_dependencies(cv_playground opencv)
target_link_libraries(cv_playground Threads::Threads ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS} opencv_core opencv_dnn opencv_features2d opencv_flann opencv_highgui opencv_imgcodecs)
```

Error message (still get undefined reference to dlopen, dlclose, ...)

```
[ 90%] Linking CXX executable cv_playground
/home/syonekura/CLionProjects/cv_playground/cmake-build-debug/opencv/lib/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o): In function `cv::TLSData<cv::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadID>::createDataInstance() const':
system.cpp:(.text._ZNK2cv7TLSDataINS_12_GLOBAL__N_18ThreadIDEE18createDataInstanceEv+0x37): undefined reference to `__itt_thread_set_name_ptr__3_0'
/home/syonekura/CLionProjects/cv_playground/cmake-build-debug/opencv/lib/libopencv_core.a(opencl_core.cpp.o): In function `GetHandle(char const*)':
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL9GetHandlePKc+0x7): undefined reference to `dlopen'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL9GetHandlePKc+0x1e): undefined reference to `dlsym'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL9GetHandlePKc+0x53): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/home/syonekura/CLionProjects/cv_playground/cmake-build-debug/opencv/lib/libopencv_core.a(opencl_core.cpp.o): In function `opencl_check_fn(int)':
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL15opencl_check_fni+0x3f): undefined reference to `dlsym'
```

Comment: `I tried to add them in the target_link_libraries for example but still gives me the same errors.` - Add that attempt into your question post. And post **exact** error message (which includes filenames).

Comment: @Tsyvarev added the attempt and an extract of the error message (the original it's quite long but it's basically the same error message for different functions)

Comment: As you can see from the error messages, the errors are caused by `opencv` library. For resolve them properly, you need to place needed libraries **after** the `opencv` one. But your code exposes opposite case. See that answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/24675715.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1):

So I've had quite a few issues with this myself. Cmake should essentially be used just to build the OpenCV library. Provided you're using an ubuntu machine you want to do this:

```
# Update and upgrade packages
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade

# Remove any existing versions of x264
sudo apt-get remove x264 libx264-dev

# Install OS Libraries

# Install Dependencies
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential checkinstall cmake pkg-config yasm gfortran git
sudo apt-get -y install libjpeg8-dev libjasper-dev libpng12-dev
# Used for Ubuntu 16.04
sudo apt-get -y install libtiff5-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libdc1394-22-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libxine2-dev libv4l-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libqt4-dev libgtk2.0-dev libtbb-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libatlas-base-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libtheora-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev
sudo apt-get -y install x264 v4l-utils

# Install Optional Dependencies
sudo apt-get -y install libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
sudo apt-get -y install libgoogle-glog-dev libgflags-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libgphoto2-dev libeigen3-dev libhdf5-dev doxygen

# Download OpenCV from Github
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
cd opencv
git checkout 3.3.0
cd ..

# Download opencv_contrib from Github
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
cd opencv_contrib
git checkout 3.3.0
cd ..

# Compile and Install OpenCV with contrib
# Create build directory inside opencv directory
cd opencv
mkdir build
cd build

# Run CMake with the following options
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
      -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
      -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
      -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
      -D WITH_TBB=ON \
      -D WITH_V4L=ON \
      -D WITH_QT=ON \
      -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
      -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules \
      -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..

# Compile and Install
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo sh -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf'
sudo ldconfig
```

You can cherry pick the parts that are most relevant, but essentially what this entails is making the OpenCV library available to your project. You can then either use a make file to make your project, or you can run a command as so:

> c++  `pkg-config --cflags opencv`   filename.cpp  `pkg-config --libs opencv` -o filename

This creates an executable called filename

Comment: I know how to build and install OpenCV. What I'm trying to achieve is to create a cmake file to install OpenCV as a dependency for my project